# How can i send close command to a CMD process by PID

Tags: c#, cmd, process, command-line-interface, pid

This process is started by selenium

So i do not have control over it how i start it

However, the CMD process have X button

Can i programmatically call that X button by PID?

[image]

C# 4.6.2
windows 8.1

I am able to kill the process however it is not making the same effect as X button click

Comment: Surely this is the same as your other question just wrapped differently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of my code using system command taskkill:

```
//starts a command
public static int RunCommandAndWait(string command, string args)
{
    int result = -1;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = command;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

    if (p.Start())
    {
        p.WaitForExit();
        result = p.ExitCode;
    }

    p.Dispose();
    return result;
}

//kills a process using its pid and above method
public static void KillProcessTree(int processId)
{
    RunCommandAndWait("taskkill", String.Format("/pid {0} /f /t", processId));
    try
    {
        Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        if (p != null)
            KillProcessTree(processId); //this sometimes may be needed
    }catch(Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need find [window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id) and [send message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083954/send-message-in-c-sharp) to the window

`SendMessage(mbWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);`

like have described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926107/force-to-close-messagebox-programmatically)

Comment: i have no access to the process other than its PID

Comment: Excuse me - are you have access to the Win32API on this system ?

Comment: i see now let met try

Comment: In general you don't need access to the other process, you just need rights for using functions from one system dll (user32.dll) - this is enough

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
// Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
// Free resources associated with process.
myProcess.Close();
```

Comment: Have you checked if your process has any childs that are preventing it from closing? 
The request to exit the process by calling CloseMainWindow does not force the application to quit. The application can ask for user verification before quitting, or it can refuse to quit. like described in the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: CloseMainWindow only works when a process has window. This process does not have a window. It starts in command line.